# Change the layout on button click

Tags: java, javafx, interface, fxml

I want to change the page when I click the button. I can do it as soon as the program open, but I want to change the center of the Main class' BorderPane when I clicked the button. (I have a number of buttons and I want to go to different controllers with them). 
I want to change the center of the Main Controller without changing it. I tried so many things but couldn't do that. On action method addClicked is working but doesn't change the center controller to another controller.

I have Main.class, MainController.java and AddTaskController.java.

Main.class:

```
package application;

import java.io.IOException;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;


public class Main extends Application {
    private Stage window;
    private BorderPane layout;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        window = primaryStage;
        try {
            MainController con1 = showMainView();
            setLayout(con1.setLay("addssss.fxml"));
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void setLayout(HBox lay){
        layout.setCenter(lay);
    }

    private MainController showMainView() throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(Main.class.getResource("MainInterface.fxml"));
        layout = loader.load();
        Scene scene = new Scene(layout);
        window.setScene(scene);
        window.show();
        return loader.getController();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

MainController.java:

```
package application;

import java.io.IOException;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;

public class MainController {

    @FXML
    void addClicked(ActionEvent e) throws IOException{

    }

    public HBox setLay(String kaynak) throws IOException{
        HBox layout;
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(AddTaskController.class.getResource(kaynak));
        layout = loader.load(); 
        return layout;
    }

}
```

And AddTaskController.java (There is no code):

```
package application;


public class AddTaskController {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is your problem? What have you tried to solve it?

If you want to change the layout of your buttons, I see two possible solutions.

1. You remove the old layout from your scene (or where ever it was added). Then you add the buttons to a new layout and add the new layout to your scene. (Though I am not sure if this works or not, since the SceneGraph only allows components to be added once).
2. You have multiple layouts prepared with different buttons and in every layout there is one button calling the "addClicked" method. So there are different Buttons in different Layouts behaving the same way. (You can also prepare a new Layout with new Buttons on the fly, like the first solution does)

Comment: I have main controller which has buttons and menu. And another controller in the center of the main controller which has check boxes, textviews etc. (I set these from Main.java). What I want to do is, when I click the button in main controller I want it to change the controller which is in the center of the main controller. Shortly, I want the change the controller in the middle without changing the main controller.